# Windows: How to get current user's AppData when run as administrator

Tags: windows, uac, appdata

```
WCHAR buff[100];
GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"APPDATA", buff, 100);
```

current user isn't administrator, when running as administrator, I get administrator's `APPDATA`.

Is there a way to get current user's `APPDATA`?

Comment: And you think this a good idea because...

Comment: 1. need running as administrator to write registry / register dll.
2. need to access/write another application's profiles(in current user's AppData).

Comment: Split the job into two parts, one of which runs as administrator and the other runs as the current user.

Comment: Yes, two processes is a solution.